# PHP resizing and blurring an image

Tags: php, image, resize, blur

I have a question. I already have this code (I am not the best coder, but at least it works xD) for image blurring and resizing. It takes too long, so I wanted to ask if there's a way to make it faster:

```
$file = $data['image'];
$blurs = 50;

$extension = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if ($extension == 'jpg' || $extension == 'jpeg')
{
    $width=300;
    $size=GetimageSize($file);
    $height=round($width*$size[1]/$size[0]);
    $images_orig = ImageCreateFromJPEG($file);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $blurs; $i++) {
        imagefilter($images_orig, IMG_FILTER_GAUSSIAN_BLUR);
    }
    $photoX = ImagesX($images_orig);
    $photoY = ImagesY($images_orig);
    $images_fin = ImageCreateTrueColor($width, $height);
    ImageCopyResampled($images_fin, $images_orig, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width+1, $height+1, $photoX, $photoY);

    imagejpeg($images_fin, null, 100);
}

else if ($extension == 'png')
{

}

else
{
    return 'error';
}

imagedestroy($images_fin);
```

Comment: You dont have access to imagemagick ?

Comment: @JelleKeizer I need it to be automatic, I really don't have time to edit every image on my own.

Comment: you can useimagemagick from php to automate it http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.examples-1.php if its installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `IMG_FILTER_GAUSSIAN_BLUR` filter is quite slow. Calling it 50 times won't help. You could try some combination of filters.

Try to put a

```
imagefilter($images_orig, IMG_FILTER_SMOOTH, -2);
```

in front of the loop and reduce the loop count (`$blurs`) to something like 3.

Comment: The thing is that the image is pretty huge and if i use only few blurs, the effect is not visible after image resizing. Maybe there's a way to resize the image first and then blur it out?

Comment: Did oversee the rescaling part. It sure makes sense to first scale it down and then blur it. However, calling the `IMG_FILTER_GAUSSIAN_BLUR` filter more than even 10 times will still be slow. And you will have similar effect as if you first use a `IMG_FILTER_SMOOTH` filter and then `IMG_FILTER_GAUSSIAN_BLUR`.